# Do I need to start over? - Ionic 4

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic4, ionic-native

I have spent about 2 weeks creating an app and have made good progress. However, when I have been looking in to eventually deploying my app I encountered the Ionic Dashboard. Here it gives options to create an app, not to link an existing app. I created my app using the Ionic CLI, and have it connected to GitHub.

Since I’ve not got it synced with my app Dashboard and the only option given is to “Create New App”, do I need to start over?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you don't have to start over, you have to create a new app in the Ionic Dashboard and then link it to your existing app, following these [instructions](https://ionicframework.com/docs/appflow/quickstart/connect).

Let me know if you have anymore questions.